# Finding out which is the failed drive on Intel SRCASRB RAID Controller

Tags: raid, hardware, storage, hardware-raid

There is very old server with Intel RAID SRCASRB Controller with 4 x WD5003ABYX-0 500GB drives connected to it in RAID5 array.
One of those drives has failed and I want to replace it. Since server is old tower case, drives are screwed manually into 3.5" bays. There is no HDD backplane, so there is no LED indicating which drive has failed.

Intel RAID Web Console 2 only shows disk model number and doesn't show serial number, so I have no clue which drive should I replace.

[image]

Any ideas how to find out which physical drive has failed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had old v2.XX Web Console 2 version. Upgraded to v15.XX where they included detection of drive serial numbers.